how to make the window dynamically resizable and make the GUI responsive to the resizable window without changing the original aligntment
i want the window dynamically resizable and the GUI reactive to its resizable window without changing the original alignment and functions of each buttons and without changing the original logic of the GUI. this is the whole code i hope i can get answers here
public HardMode_GUI(ElementalGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.elementManager = new ElementManager();

    setTitle("ELEMENTALS: Hard Mode");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
    setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel() {
        ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("hardbg.png"));

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    };
    mainPanel.setLayout(null);
    add(mainPanel);

    roundLabel = new JLabel("Round 1", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    roundLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
    roundLabel.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    roundLabel.setBounds(200, 10, 400, 40);
    mainPanel.add(roundLabel);

    timerLabel = new JLabel("Time left: 10 seconds", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    timerLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    timerLabel.setForeground(new Color(255, 215, 0));
    timerLabel.setBounds(200, 50, 400, 40);
    timerLabel.setVisible(false);
    mainPanel.add(timerLabel);

    resultLabel = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    resultLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    resultLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    resultLabel.setBounds(200, 100, 400, 80);
    mainPanel.add(resultLabel);

    balanceLabel = new JLabel("Your Balance: " + game.getPlayer().getMoney(), SwingConstants.LEFT);
    balanceLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    balanceLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    balanceLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 40);
    mainPanel.add(balanceLabel);

    systemBalanceLabel = new JLabel("System Balance: " + game.getSystem().getMoney(), SwingConstants.LEFT);
    systemBalanceLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    systemBalanceLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    systemBalanceLabel.setBounds(10, 400, 200, 40);
    mainPanel.add(systemBalanceLabel);
    setupElementButtons(mainPanel);

    nextRoundButton = new JButton("Next Round");
    nextRoundButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
    nextRoundButton.setBounds((getWidth() - 200) / 2, 390, 200, 40);
    nextRoundButton.setVisible(false);
    nextRoundButton.addActionListener(e -> startNextRound());
    mainPanel.add(nextRoundButton);
    startNextRound();
    setVisible(true);
    }

private void showPowerUpSelection() {
JDialog powerUpDialog = new JDialog(this, "Power-Ups", true);
powerUpDialog.setSize(800, 500);
powerUpDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
powerUpDialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel() {
    ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bg7.png"));

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    };
backgroundPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
powerUpDialog.add(backgroundPanel);

JLabel choosePowerUpLabel = new JLabel("Choose Your Power-Up");
choosePowerUpLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
choosePowerUpLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
choosePowerUpLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); 
choosePowerUpLabel.setBounds(0, 50, 800, 40); 
backgroundPanel.add(choosePowerUpLabel);

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setOpaque(false); 
buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 100)); 
String[] powerUps = {"Double Bet", "Steal Money", "Block Element"};
String[] powerUpIcons = {"doublebet.png", "stealmoney.png", "blockelement.png"};
int buttonWidth = 200, buttonHeight = 300;

for (int i = 0; i < powerUps.length; i++) {
    int index = i;

    
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(powerUpIcons[i]));
    Image scaledImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(buttonWidth, buttonHeight, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon resizedIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);

    JButton button = new JButton(resizedIcon);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(buttonWidth, buttonHeight));
    button.setToolTipText(powerUps[i]);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);

    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        selectedPowerUp = index;
        powerUpDialog.dispose();
        applyPowerUp(index);
    });

    buttonPanel.add(button);
}

backgroundPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

powerUpDialog.setVisible(true);

}
private void showBlockElementSelection() {
JDialog blockElementDialog = new JDialog(this, "Block Element", true);
blockElementDialog.setSize(800, 500);
blockElementDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
blockElementDialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Select an Element to Block");
titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
titleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
titleLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 0, 10, 0)); 

JPanel backgroundPanel = new JPanel() {
    ImageIcon backgroundImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("bg7.png"));

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
};
backgroundPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
backgroundPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 30, 20)); 
buttonsPanel.setOpaque(false); 

String[] hybridElements = elementManager.getHybridElements();
String[] hybridIcons = {"steam.png", "mud.png", "dust.png", "lava.png"};

for (int i = 0; i < hybridElements.length; i++) {
    String element = hybridElements[i];

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(hybridIcons[i]));
    Image scaledImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(120, 175, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon resizedIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);

    JButton button = new JButton(resizedIcon);
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 175));
    button.setToolTipText(element);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);

    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Block Element Activated! " + element + " is now blocked.");
        blockElementDialog.dispose();
    });

    buttonsPanel.add(button);
}

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
centerPanel.setOpaque(false);
centerPanel.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(50, 0, 50, 0)); 

backgroundPanel.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
blockElementDialog.add(backgroundPanel);
blockElementDialog.setVisible(true);

}
private void setupElementButtons(JPanel mainPanel) {
    int buttonWidth = 120;
    int buttonHeight = 175;
    int numButtons = 4;
    int spacing = 30;
    int totalWidth = (buttonWidth * numButtons) + (spacing * (numButtons - 1));
    int startX = (getWidth() - totalWidth) / 2;

    elementButtons = new JButton[numButtons];
    elementButtons[0] = createElementButton(mainPanel, "steam.png", "Fire+Water = Steam", startX, 200, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, spacing, 0);
    elementButtons[1] = createElementButton(mainPanel, "mud.png", "Water+Earth = Mud", startX, 200, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, spacing, 1);
    elementButtons[2] = createElementButton(mainPanel, "dust.png", "Earth+Air = Dust", startX, 200, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, spacing, 2);
    elementButtons[3] = createElementButton(mainPanel, "lava.png", "Earth+Fire = Lava", startX, 200, buttonWidth, buttonHeight, spacing, 3);
}

    private JButton createElementButton(JPanel mainPanel, String iconPath, String element, int startX, int y, int width, int height, int spacing, int index) {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(iconPath));
    Image scaledImage = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon resizedIcon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);

    int xPosition = startX + (index * (width + spacing));

    JButton button = new JButton(resizedIcon);
    button.setBounds(xPosition, y, width, height);
    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    button.setFocusPainted(false);
    button.setDisabledIcon(resizedIcon);
    button.addActionListener(e -> handlePlayerChoice(element));
    mainPanel.add(button);

    return button;
    }
    
    private void showGameMechanics() {
    JDialog mechanicsDialog = new JDialog(this, "GAME MECHANICS", true);
    mechanicsDialog.setSize(400, 300);
    mechanicsDialog.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    mechanicsDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    mechanicsDialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JTextArea mechanicsText = new JTextArea(
            " ‣ Hard Mode has 4 Rounds.\n\n" +
            " ‣ The balance left from the Easy and Medium Mode continues in Hard Mode.\n" +
            " ‣ First, you must choose your power-up then you can proceed on placing your bet.\n\n" +
            "   The power-ups are\n" +
            "   1. DOUBLE BET(allows the player to double the bet and will add to the player's balance if the player wins otherwise the player's loss adds to the system's balance.)\n\n" + 
            "   2. STEAL MONEY(allows the player to steal balance from the system between 50 and 100 pesos.)\n\n" + 
            "   3. BLOCK ELEMENT (allows the player to prevent the system from selecting a specific hybrid element during the round.)\n\n" + 
            " ‣ After placing the bet, the power-up you chose will be activated then you can pick your card.\n\n" +
            " ‣ It has a timer of 10 seconds while choosing an element (HYBRID ELEMENTS). \n" +
                "If the time is up, a random element is auto-selected.\n\n" + 
            " ‣ The game ends when either the player(you) or the system doesn't have enough balance to continue. \n\n"

    );
    mechanicsText.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    mechanicsText.setEditable(false);
    mechanicsText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    mechanicsText.setLineWrap(true);
    mechanicsText.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    mechanicsText.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    mechanicsDialog.add(new JScrollPane(mechanicsText), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
    JButton okButton = new JButton("Ready?");
    okButton.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 16));
    okButton.addActionListener(e -> mechanicsDialog.dispose());
    mechanicsDialog.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mechanicsDialog.setVisible(true);
}
    
private void updateBalances() {
    balanceLabel.setText("Your Balance: " + game.getPlayer().getMoney());
    systemBalanceLabel.setText("System Balance: " + game.getSystem().getMoney());
}
private void startNextRound() {
roundsPlayed++;
if (roundsPlayed > 4) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Hard Mode Complete! Congratulations! You have finished the game.");
    System.exit(0);
}

if (isFirstRound) {
    showGameMechanics();
    isFirstRound = false; 
}

roundLabel.setText("Round " + roundsPlayed);
resultLabel.setText("");
nextRoundButton.setVisible(false);

enableElementButtons();
showPowerUpSelection(); 
startCountdown(); 
}

private void enableElementButtons() {
    for (JButton button : elementButtons) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

private void disableElementButtons() {
for (JButton button : elementButtons) {
    button.setEnabled(false);
    button.setDisabledIcon(button.getIcon()); 
    }
}

private void startCountdown() {
timeLeft = 10; 
timerLabel.setText("Time left: " + timeLeft + " seconds");
timerLabel.setVisible(true);

countdownTimer = new Timer(1000, e -> {
    timeLeft--;
    timerLabel.setText("Time left: " + timeLeft + " seconds");

    if (timeLeft <= 0) {
        countdownTimer.stop();
        handlePlayerChoice(elementManager.getRandomHybridElement());
    }
});
countdownTimer.start();

}
private boolean isBlockedElement(String element) {
return element.equals("Earth+Fire = Lava") && selectedPowerUp == 2;

}
private void handlePlayerChoice(String playerElement) {
countdownTimer.stop();
disableElementButtons();

String systemElement = elementManager.getRandomHybridElement();
while (selectedPowerUp == 2 && isBlockedElement(systemElement)) {
systemElement = elementManager.getRandomHybridElement();
}

String winner = elementManager.determineWinner(playerElement, systemElement);

if (winner.equals("Player")) {
    game.getPlayer().updateMoney(betAmount);
    game.getSystem().updateMoney(-betAmount);
    resultLabel.setText(String.format(
            "<html><div style='text-align: center;'>%s wins this round!<br>%s chose: %s<br>System chose: %s</div></html>",
            game.getPlayer().getName(), game.getPlayer().getName(), playerElement, systemElement));
} else if (winner.equals("System")) {
    game.getPlayer().updateMoney(-betAmount);
    game.getSystem().updateMoney(betAmount);
    resultLabel.setText(String.format(
            "<html><div style='text-align: center;'>System wins this round!<br>%s chose: %s<br>System chose: %s</div></html>",
            game.getPlayer().getName(), playerElement, systemElement));
} else {
    resultLabel.setText(String.format(
            "<html><div style='text-align: center;'>It's a tie!<br>%s chose: %s<br>System chose: %s</div></html>",
            game.getPlayer().getName(), playerElement, systemElement));
}

updateBalances();

if (game.getPlayer().getMoney() <= 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over! You have no money left. The System wins!");
    System.exit(0);
} else if (game.getSystem().getMoney() <= 0) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Congratulations! The system has no money left. You win!");
    System.exit(0);
}

nextRoundButton.setVisible(true);

}
i want the window dynamically resizable and the GUI reactive to its resizable window without changing the original alignment and functions of each buttons and without changing the original logic of the GUI. this is the whole code i hope i can get answers here

don't use a null layout. Use a layout manager: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing///layout/

Edit your question to include a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE, compile, run, and test.  Explain exactly what "GUI reactive" means.  Do the Swing components increase and decrease in size or just maintain their position?
